# Remove space between widgets in Row - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using two widgets(Text and Flatbutton) in Row. Whatever I do, there is space between them. I don't want any space between them how to do that?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("TextColor checking"),
    ),
    body:
Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
             Text("Already have a account?"),
               FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text("Login"),
                  textColor: Colors.indigo,
                ),


          ],
        ),
       ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want like this: Already have a account? Login

Comment: Can you share some screenshot and code please?

Comment: Posted an answer for you. Take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a simple text like that, dont use row or flat button. Use Rich text instead.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TextColor checking"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
              children: <TextSpan>[
                TextSpan(
                  text: "Don't have an account? ",
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    //Add any decorations here
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  ),
                  recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                    ..onTap = () {
                      //Enter the function here
                    },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the space because you are using a `FlatButton` and `FlatButton`s has padding by default. You should use a `GestureDetector` instead.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TextColor checking"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Already have a account? "),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Text(
                  "Login",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.indigo,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and in seams the space is not between the components, but its is the padding of the FlatButton. to remove that, you will have use another component instead of Flat Button. try the below

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("TextColor checking"),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Already have a account?"),
              RawMaterialButton(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                      5.0), // optional, in order to add additional space around text     if needed
                  child: Text('Login'),
                  onPressed: () {})
//               FlatButton(
//                 onPressed: () {},
//                 child: Text("Login"),
//                 textColor: Colors.indigo,
//               ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```